# Finding pitch and changing it in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, pitch, pitch-shifting

Good morning, I'm having trouble with pitch finding and shifting in MATLAB. The program compiles but when i try to sound the shifted track it exits a strange sound and the pitch found isn't correct. What's the problem?

```
 [audioIn,fs] = audioread('Silae.wav');
 [f0,idx] = pitch(audioIn,fs);

 subplot(3,1,1)    %2.1.1
 plot(audioIn)
 ylabel('Amplitude')

 subplot(3,1,2)    %2.1.2
 plot(idx,f0)
 ylabel('Pitch (Hz)')
 xlabel('Sample Number')

 [f1,idx] = pitch(audioIn,0.3*fs); 
 subplot(3,1,3)
 plot(idx,f1)
 ylabel('Pitch n (Hz)')
 xlabel('Sample Number n')
 [f1,idx] = pitch(audioIn,3*fs);  %2 o 4
 subplot(3,1,3)
 plot(idx,f1)
 ylabel('Pitch n (Hz)')
 xlabel('Sample Number n')
 sound(audioIn);
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [your own question you deleted by now](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54332867/5211833) Note that it is against Stack Overflow policy to 'bump' posts by deleting them. This can get you a question ban. Instead, improve your question as best as you can, and, if you have enough reputation, [set a bounty on it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). You are not entitled to get help, it's a volunteer service after all, so please don't abuse the system.

Answer (score 3):

The function [`pitch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/ref/pitch.html) returns the fundamental frequencies of the audio vector `audioIn` and the locations of these frequencies. This function does not modify its input, so when you do `pitch(audioIn,0.3*fs)`, `audioIn` will remain unchanged.

So, regarding to what you perform on `audioIn`, your code could be summarized as:

```
[audioIn,fs] = audioread('Silae.wav');
sound(audioIn);
```

By default, the function [`sound`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sound.html) (without argument about Fs):

> sound(y) sends audio signal y to the speaker at **the default sample rate of 8192 hertz.**

So, the problem is, if your input `Silae.wav` file is at 44100 Hz, by playing it at 8192 Hz, you will play it about 5 times slower that you should, making it weird and deep sound.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm often confused with the paramethers of the functions. However what can i do to shift the pitch?

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking the green check mark, so people know you consider the answer as correct. I'm looking for some interesting pitch shift links.